# How to manager control sockets and transfer sockets?

Tags: linux, sockets, networking

We are developing a network application based on C/S, in this application the server needs to transfer files to clients and sometimes receive files from clients. So in the server application, for every client it needs to create a control socket and many transfer sockets.

My question is how we can create and define a socket as role of control socket or transfer socket? ( below are deleted: And how can the server application distinguish between the control socket and the transfer sockets? ). Currently the servers use a listening socket, and for all new connections established  by accept(listening socket), it stores them equally in an array, finally lets the client register them to the server as control sockets or transfer sockets(means before transferring a file, the client needs to tell which socket it wants to use as control socket and which sockets it want to use as transfer sockets).

I don't think this is a good patter for creating control sockets and transfer sockets between server application and the clients. So is there any other patters that is suitable for this kind of problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how we can create this control socket and all the other transfer sockets?

Same way you create any other socket. I don't understand the question.

> And how can the server application distinguish between the control socket and the transfer sockets?

By being told by the client, and remembering it in some sort of data structure per client. Or maybe you should use different listening ports for control sockets and transfer sockets. Or maybe the transfer socket should be a callback as in FTP.

Comment: 1. Regarding the first question, I mean how can the server create and define a socket as role of control socket or transfer socket? Does it create control sockets and transfer sockets equally (at the same time)? or Does it create controls sockets and let the "control sockets" class to create transfer sockets?

Comment: 2. Regarding the second question, thanks I think you are right, actually this is also how the FileZilla OSS does. But does it mean that the server has to be told by the client for every transfer sockets? There have to be some application-layer handshakes before creating every transfer socket?

Comment: @StevePeng (1) As I said, I don't understand the question. The server doesn't create sockets at all, it accepts them. (2) I suggest you have a good look at the FTP RFC. The client tells the server which port to open, then the server opens it.